# Git command for rollback rewriten history

Tags: git, undo

I am doing some experiments with git. On my branch I did

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -name '*.java' -exec sed -i -e \ 's/stringToReplace/replacement/g' {} \;" 777b7d777c7777777dc16a8a939a8cdbabc28086..HEAD
```

That is rewriting the history. I did not push the changes. Now I am wondering how I can reset that thing? I want to rollback that rewriting. What is the easiest way for that? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: git doesn't "re-write" history. It only adds new history. What does `sed -i -e` do?

Comment: @evolutionxbox git can absolutely rewrite history, and does in this case.

Comment: @jhpratt can you give an example? Even rebase doesn’t rewrite what’s already there.

Comment: filter-brach rewrites history. A quick search will yiekd many examples

Comment: @jhpratt thanks, I did some research. My comment is still good, git doesn't remove the old commits it only adds new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `git rebase`, it stores the original commit ID of your branch in `.git/refs/original/refs/heads/<branchname>`.  If you want to undo your rebase, you can just run:

```
git reset --hard original/refs/heads/master
```

This assumes that you are on your `master` branch; if not, change the branch name after `heads/` appropriately.

Alternatively, if you just want to reset your local repository to the state of the upstream repository, you can:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This would reset your local branch to the `master` branch on your remote named `origin`.

Comment: Also, I like to remind people that if you're not entirely sure you're doing the right thing, you can always make a copy of your repository (`cp -a myrepo mytestrepo`) and try out these commands in the copy and make sure they do what you want.